# encodingURIcomponent on front end to send to backend express server

Tags: javascript

I have never used encodeURIcomponent before, and for some reason, the documentation I am reading is not helpful, and what I have tried thus far is not effective. (still learning)

I am trying to send a url to my backend express server upon search, that will return a response. Can anyone provide some insight as to how I would do that?

Here is my front end:

```
async function getSample() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/lookup/https://google.com');
  const data = await res.text();
  console.log(data);
    }
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', getSample);
```

relevent piece of my backend:

```
steve.open(req.params.url).then(function(site) {
```

Comment: `const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/lookup/https://google.com');` that is not a valid url

Comment: Do `fetch('http://localhost:3000/lookup/'+encodeURIComponent('https://google.com'))`

Comment: @blex tried that and get ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier``` The url google does not need to be there, but don't I include that to tell the form the proper format? If I am not mistaken the Goolgle url is required?

Comment: I just tried it, it works as-is, with the snippet I shared above. (on the server, I used the route `/lookup/:url`). Please show the code causing the error, so we can get a better look at what might be causing a problem

Comment: @blex the error was mine. It works when I tried it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
async function getSample() {
  const uri = encodeURIComponent('https://google.com')
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/lookup/${uri}`);
  const data = await res.text();
  console.log(data);
    }
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', getSample);
```

`encodeURIComponent('https://google.com')` gives you `https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com` which is permitted as a path component in a URI or as a query string parameter.

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3

Comment: Thanks for this. So if I wanted the url to be ```localhost/lookup/google.com``` How would I accomplish this? And what should my backend express server look like then? Would this look right for the app.get? ```app.get('/lookup/:url```

Comment: @Max.California Yes, as long as you `encodeURIComponent` that value, `/lookup/:url` will work (I tried it)

Comment: Got it. Just tried ```encodeURIComponent('google.com')``` and it I get a ```Invalid URL: google.com```

Comment: Thats because its not a valid URI. If you want to remove the protocol on the front-end you have to add a protocol on the backend to get a valid URI.

Comment: @max What does the protocol look like?

Comment: `https://`. Of course you don't actually know the protocol if the user is supplying the links and you strip it off.